# C++/CLI stack semantics equivalent of C#'s existing-object using statement?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, idisposable, using, finally

I know that the C++/CLI equivalent to this C# code:

```
using (SomeClass x = new SomeClass(foo))
{
    // ...
}
```

is this:

```
{
    SomeClass x(foo);
    // ...
}
```

But is there a similarly succinct and RAII-like way to express this:

```
using (SomeClass x = SomeFunctionThatReturnsThat(foo))
{
    // ...
}
```

Or:

```
SomeClass x = SomeFunctionThatReturnsThat(foo);
using (x)
{
    // ...
}
```

?  The closest working example I have is this:

```
SomeClass^ x = SomeFunctionThatReturnsThat(foo);
try
{
    // ...
}
finally
{
    if (x != nullptr) { delete x; }
}
```

But that doesn't seem as nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`msclr::auto_handle<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/auto-handle-class) is a smart pointer for managed types:

```
#include <msclr/auto_handle.h>

{
    msclr::auto_handle<SomeClass> x(SomeFunctionThatReturnsThat(foo));
    // ...
}

// or

SomeClass^ x = SomeFunctionThatReturnsThat(foo);
{
    msclr::auto_handle<SomeClass> y(x);
    // ...
}
```